# Django: How to get an element from list by using index on templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

This is my current code:

```
{% for question in model.get_questions %}
 {% with counter=forloop.counter %}
  {{ question }} {{ model.get_fields.counter }} <br>
 {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

When I only print `counter` it works, when I type any number instead of `model.get_fields.counter` but in this way that I do does not works. What should I do?

Comment: This is not possible in Django templates. You've three options now: 1) Either do this in the views and pass the results as context vars to the template; 2) Write custom template tag or filter to do this; 3) Switch to Jinja2 template engine.

Comment: or use for each field in model.get_fields